# Load a resource from an assembly without locking the dll file

Tags: f#, .net-remoting

I'm trying to load a resource from an assembly without locking the dll file.

I'm trying the following, which is similar to something I've used before in C#:

```
type IEmbeddedResourceReader =
    abstract ReadResource : referencedAssemblies:string[] * asmName:string * resourceName:string -> string option

type EmbeddedResourceReader() =
    inherit MarshalByRefObject()

    interface IEmbeddedResourceReader with
        member __.ReadResource(referencedAssemblies, asmName, resourceName) =
            try
              let asmLocation = 
                referencedAssemblies
                |> Array.tryFind (fun (x:string) -> x.EndsWith(asmName + ".dll", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
              let asm = 
                match asmLocation with
                | Some asmLocation -> Assembly.LoadFrom asmLocation
                | None -> Assembly.Load(asmName)
              use sr = new StreamReader(asm.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
              Some(sr.ReadToEnd())
            with _ -> 
              None

    static member ReadResource(referencedAssemblies, resourceName:string) =
        match resourceName.Split(',') with
        | [| asmName; name |] ->
            let domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain "Embedded Resource Reader"
            try 
                let reader = domain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location,
                                                                typeof<EmbeddedResourceReader>.FullName) :?> IEmbeddedResourceReader
                reader.ReadResource(referencedAssemblies, asmName.Trim(), name.Trim())
            finally
                AppDomain.Unload domain
        | _ -> None
```

But I'm getting an InvalidCastException (Unable to cast transparent proxy to type 'IEmbeddedResourceReader'.)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed to add this for it to work:

```
    static do
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.add_AssemblyResolve(ResolveEventHandler(fun _ args -> 
            if args.Name = typeof<IEmbeddedResourceReader>.Assembly.FullName then 
                typeof<IEmbeddedResourceReader>.Assembly 
            else 
                null))
```

Thanks to @mitekm (Dmitry Morozov) for the answer

Unfortunatelly, the dll is no longer locked, but the xml and pdb files are still locked by VS :/